# Crisis Communication MicrosoftGraphRequestFail Error

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-graph-teams

According to the step Update the Request for help flow (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/sample-crisis-communication-app#update-the-request-for-help-flow)

My Channel ID is 19%3a09e59828c958486d86047491bc58XXXX%40thread.skype
different with the Channel ID with the end of thread.tacv2

Is that a problems to connect to the teams?

Because at the end , I had trigger the Team notification and I'm owner of the Team channel but the error shown as below
[image]

Here with the Error Shown

```
Forbidden. The request failed. 
Error code: 'MicrosoftGraphRequestFailed'. 
Error Message: 'Request to the Microsoft Graph failed with error: '{ "error": { "code": "Forbidden", "message": "Forbidden", "innerError": { "date": "2020-10-14T00:28:37", "request-id": "464af498-a707-49dd-8e5f-1572053e89fe", "client-request-id": "dbdab131-e774-4f84-b4a0-3543b8e8e300" } } }'.'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Power Automate app must be installed within the team. This typically happens silently the in the background, but in cases where app install is disabled in the tenant, it can't be done.

It's failing with the below message internally -- I've opened a bug to track exposing a better message here with recommendations for the end user.

You'll want to install the "Flow" (soon to be "Power Automate") app into the team. Manage Team -> Apps ->  More Apps

```
Failed to install Flow app for team '4a3c74d4-a801-44fc-8cb6-4f6ba8397621' with status code 'Forbidden' and error message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-10-14T00:28:37",
      "request-id": "464af498-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1572053e89fe",
      "client-request-id": "dbdab131-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-3543b8e8e300"
    }
  }
}'.
```